# What is the best way to append a row to matrix?

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, apache-commons

I am trying to append a row to a pre-existing matrix. I wrote some code (shown below) that does the trick, but I can't help but feel there is a better way to do this (or perhaps there is already an Apache Commons function which does this???).

**Code**

```
private RealMatrix appendRow(RealMatrix m) {

    double[][] mData = m.getData();
    double[][] newData = new double[m.getRowDimension()+1][m.getColumnDimension()];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowDimension(); i++) {
        newData[i] = mData[i];
    }

    newData[m.getRowDimension()] = new double[m.getColumnDimension()];

    return MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(newData);
}
```

**Example usage and output**

```
RealMatrix m = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(new double[][]{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}});
Log.i("m", m.toString());

// Array2DRowRealMatrix{{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0}}

m = appendRow(m);
Log.i("m", m.toString());

// Array2DRowRealMatrix{{1.0,2.0,3.0},{4.0,5.0,6.0},{0.0,0.0,0.0}}
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `RealMatrix` is your custom class you'd need to write some of the code anyways. There are libaries like Apache Commons Lang which has a method `ArrayUtils.add(array, new element)` (actually a bunch of overloads) but your code isn't that complex to justify adding an additional dependency just for that.

A few notes though:

`double[][] newData = new double[m.getRowDimension()+1][m.getColumnDimension()];` already creates the "inner" arrays, i.e. the rows, so `newData[m.getRowDimension()] = new double[m.getColumnDimension()];` is unnecessary.

Also note that `newData[i] = mData[i];` risks multiple matrices using the same rows and thus changing one would change others as well. Thus I'd suggest you make a copy using `System.arrayCopy(mData[i], 0, newData[i], 0, mData[i].length )` instead of `newData[i] = mData[i]`.

To illustrate the last point try `RealMatrix m2 = appendRow(m);`, then change one of the copied elements (e.g. change [0][0] to 7) and print both `m` and `m2`.

Answer (score 0):

You go the right way. The only think I can add is to replace this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowDimension(); i++) {
    newData[i] = mData[i];
}
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m.getRowDimension(); i++) {
    System.arraycopy(mData[i], 0, newData[i], 0, mData[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it isn't a problem to reuse the row arrays (which you are doing in your current code), it would be easiest just to replace the for loop with:

```
double[][] newData = Arrays.copyOf(data, 0, data.length + 1);
```